# Need help enabling android builds on Unity3d

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

I am a .Net developer and hence completely unaware of java terminology. Sadly, to build my Unity4 games, I need to install the jdk and other android tools. I have already downloaded sdk bundle for android, and multiple versions of jdk and jre. But, this whole thing is so confusing and off-putting.

Kindly help me figure out which version of jdk and android sdk is best suitable for Unity4. I am currently running Unity4 on Windows 8 x64 machine.

Also, once this setup is done, can I simply build the apk and transfer that to my phone without ever going to code in Java? Or do I need to learn parts of Java language?

Comment: Did you see [Unity - Getting Started with Android Development](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html) and [Unity - Android SDK Setup](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html). In general you don't need to code in java for Android or in Objective-C on iOS except for writing or using plugins.

Comment: I did saw that. Following the same guide. But, it asks me to download jdk and android sdk so that I can build the game to apk file. Sadly, that is what I am having trouble with. too many jdk versions to choose from, and no one seems to work fine for me, somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions from Justin and on Unity forums, here is what I did.

Installed the 32bit and 64bit version of JDK. Installed only the latest android platform. Upgraded Unity to 4.1. It finally works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Unity only works with the x86 version of the JDK so make sure you have that and not the x64 version. The minimal install of of the Android SDK should work for you, but this will also depend on your phone, you should explicitly install the Android SDK that is running on your phone as well to make testing easier. Run the various setups and install to default locations. Ensure that Unity4 is *NOT* running during these installs.

Once everything is installed, configure the path in Unity4 to point to your Android SDK. If you have not modified that path in Unity, and you install the JDK and ADK to the standard locations on your system, i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)... then Unity will pick up the SDK. This page explains the location to put your SDKs http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

From that point, you should be able to build your game to work on Android. In the Android build settings make sure you set the version of Android to whatever your phone runs. If you phone is an older model, e.g. an LG P999 running 2.2 then switch to that version of the SDK in Unity, don't build for the latest and greatest.

You can transfer your APK to the phone in a number of different ways, but unless you are signing the game for the app store, you need to ensure you have enabled debugging and the ability to run applications from any source.

Easiest way to transfer is via a USB cable between phone and computer so that when you build and test on Unity, it transfers the APK automatically for you. The other way to get your binary over is to drag and drop via Explorer and then launch from the Android handset. Another way, if you want to host the APK on a website, is opening up a website URL via the browser on your Android handset.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I am currently using x64 version of JDK. Will try to install x86 version too.

Also, I am receiving "No platform found" error in Unity, after using latest Java build and android sdk. I have everything installed on default location, environment variables are also set properly. Hopefully x86 version will solve that issue.

Comment: Tried using x86 edition of JDK too. Same error. Unity keeps asking location of "android-sdk-windows". I have "android-sdk" folder, selecting which does nothing.